# Populating Jenkins workspace from Gerrit/Git

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, gerrit

I have set the Gerrit-Git-Jenkins combination. I'm using the following plugins for Jenkis.

- Gerrit Trigger
- Git Client Plugin
- Jenkins GIT plugin

I'm running a dummy Jenkins job which always succeeds for development purposes. I have notices that when I push changes to Gerrit, the files don't show in the Jenkins workspace.

The repository URL which is set in the Jenkins Git configuration is `git://localhost/project` i have tried cloning it manually and `git clone git://localhost/project` gets the files which i would expect it to.

**What repository does Jenkins clone to populate its workspace?**

It clones `git://localhost/project`. I've tested this by running `git remote show origin` as the build script, and then looking at the log output.

What command does Jenkins run to populate the workspace for it seems it isn't cloning of the HEAD?

Comment: I've noticed that there is a `FETCH_HEAD` file in the .git in the workspace. `FETCH_HEAD` holds the reference to the right repository. It seems that the Workspace just isn't doing a `checkout` to the fetched repository.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jenkins does the following to populate its workspace. (names in <> represent the field names in Jenkins project configuration):

```
git clone <Repository URL>
git fetch <Refspec>
git checkout <Branch Specifier>
```

The setting which populates the workspace with the files in Gerrit which are awaiting verification are:

```
Refspec: refs/changes/*:refs/changes/*
Branches to build: $GERRIT_REFSPEC
```

This clones everything from `refs/changes/*` from Gerrit and populates the workspace from files referenced as the branch `$GERRIT_REFSPEC`. `$GERRIT_REFSPEC` is different for each new change Gerrit receives, it look something like this `refs/changes/05/5/1`.

Answer (score 3):

Just for the record, to checkout Gerrit review request (i.e., a particular patchset), configure following 3 config options in Jenkins/Hudson job:

1. `Repositories -> Repository URL`: *the git url of gerrit project* 
   (e.g., http://gerrit.corp.com/the-project)
2. `Repositories -> Refspec` (Advanced Git Settings): `refs/changes/*:refs/changes/*`
3. `Branches to be built -> Branch Specifier`): *refs/changes/XY/??XY/?* 
   (e.g., `refs/changes/24/3124/8`)

The Alan's answer is correct. It's just not clear enough imho which is why I'm trying to elaborate the answer in other words.